# How did 'gratuity' shift from meaning 'graciousness' to 'money given for favor or services'?

Tags: etymology

1. [Which semantic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change#Typology_by_Blank_(1999)) is this? I'd guess Metonymy, as the money represents the graciousness?

> Meaning "money given for favor or services" is first attested 1530s.

2. I don't know why, but I still can't understand why the graciousness would be metonymized by 'gratuity', which feels farfetched, faraway from the key semantic notion of 'money'. Why didn't some noun more straightforwardly related to 'money', metonymize the graciousness?

Comment: Hi; you've got the direction of shift in meaning reversed between the title and the body. Which direction did you mean?

Comment: A textual reference showing the use of "gratuity" to mean "graciousness" would also be useful.

Comment: @Spencer: the OED has a bunch of citations in which they claim *gratuity* means *graciousness*, but looking at them, it looks to me like they might all mean *generosity* (which was one of its meanings in French when we borrowed the word from them).

Comment: @PeterShor More like, had the word (and other foreign words like "beef") forced on us by the Normans, but I digress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didn't. The word originally came from French [*gratuit*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gratuit#French), which meant *free* (of charge). So a *gratuity* is something you give freely, when you actually don't have to (not really true anymore, because now it's expected, but a completely understandable semantic shift).

Both *grace* and *gratuity* came from the same root in [Latin,](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gratia#Latin) which meant *grace* or *thankfulness*, but there was no shift from *gracious* to *free*. And the shift from *thankfulness* to *gratuity* is perfectly understandable. Going from *thankfulness* to a gift given because you are thankful would be metonymy.

The real question is why people started using it to mean *graciousness* in English, a meaning which it seems not to have had in French when we borrowed it (*le Dictionnaire du Moyen Français* says it meant *gift* or *generosity*), and which has since died out. My guess is that they recognized the Latin root *gratia*, one of whose meanings was *grace*.

Comment: It would be interesting to explore how *gratuitous* came to mean "uncalled-for," "unnecessary," or "unwarranted."

Comment: @Robusto At a guess, it’s because gratuitous comments add *nothing of value*.

Comment: @Robusto: If something is "uncalled-for," "unnecessary," or "unwarranted," it's generally true that the giver doesn't actually have to give it. (Unlike, say, a punch in the face when somebody calls you a liar, which according to some archaic codes of honor, might be something you have to give.)